# Static files not being served on Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to serve static files in Django in development (`DEBUG=True`) mode. I have a directory structure like this:

```
my_project/
  ...
  static/
    img.png
```

In my `settings.py` I have this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATICFILE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ( 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

and in `my_project/urls.py` I have this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('app.landing.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This all seems to be correct. When I visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img.png though, I get a 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the docs: During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).

Comment: Is it a restful architecture? I mean if you have a seperate frontend app running in another port?

Comment: Did you use nginx?

Answer (score -1):

You can debug this in many different ways. Here's my approach.

main settings.py:

```
DEBUG = False
TDEBUG = True
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
import os

if settings.TDEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
         {'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')} ),
    )
```